# Describe a personality

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is one word for a person who does everything at extreme levels (mostly positive)? It is for describing a person's character that whatever he has done, he was very much dedicated, indulged and at extreme point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can refine the advice if you give more context, such as example actions.  From a general level I would suggest

- Passionate
- **Intense**
- Energetic (also puts energy in)
- Enthused
- Lively
- Industrious (also solves problems)
- Tireless
- High achiever
- Exceptional, stand out
- Devotion
- Obsessed.

Answer (score -1):

- Over-the-top
- Excessive
- Obsessive/Obsessed